# Close python Turtle module game at keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to make the Snake game using the Turtle module in Python3.
I want the program to close when the Esc key is pressed twice. Here's what i've tried so far, but I can't seem to get it working (i've previously imported the sys module):

```
def exitprogram():
    sys.exit()
   
def close():
    close = turtle.Turtle()
    close.speed(0)
    close.color("white")
    close.penup()
    close.hideturtle()
    close.goto(0,0)
    close.write("Press ESC again to exit", align="center", font = ("Courier", 24, "normal"))
    window.listen()
    window.onkeypress(exitprogram, "Escape")

window.listen()
window.onkeypress(close, "Escape")
window.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

### EDIT

Instead of using sys.exit(), i used window.bye() and that seemed to work just fine. Thanks!

Comment: How exactly does it not work? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: could you count how many times you pressed escape. And what if you press something different between first and second ESC ?

Comment: add `window.mainloop()` at the end.

Comment: @furas if i press esc twice using your solution, the program ends (just as i wanted). If i press another key between the first and second esc, nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code works for me if I add `mainloop()` which gets key/mouse events from system and sends to turtle's window. You can also use `window.bye()` to exit `mainloop()`

```
import turtle

def exitprogram():
    window.bye()

def close():
    close = turtle.Turtle()
    close.speed(0)
    #close.color("white")
    close.penup()
    close.hideturtle()
    close.goto(0,0)
    close.write("Press ESC again to exit", align="center", font = ("Courier", 24, "normal"))
    window.listen()
    window.onkeypress(exitprogram, "Escape")

window = turtle.Screen()
window.listen()
window.onkeypress(close, "Escape")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you so much!! window.bye() seemed to fix it. Now it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1):

I generally agree with @furas (+1) but I would go simpler as some methods you invoke are effectively no-ops in the context in which they are used:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def close():
    window.onkeypress(window.bye, "Escape")
    close = Turtle()
    close.hideturtle()
    # close.color("white")
    close.write("Press ESC again to exit", align="center", font=("Courier", 24, "normal"))

window = Screen()
window.onkeypress(close, "Escape")
window.listen()
window.mainloop()
```